# "cancel" link of the inline editor cannot be triggered via keyboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, inline-editor

This is a very minor annoyance but an annoyance nevertheless. If I start editing any post on Stack Overflow, there is a "cancel" link next to "Save Edits". Clicking it works just fine. However, tabbing to it and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't trigger it (interestingly, it works correctly on Meta). Which is strange given that Stack Overflow seems to be using `jQuery.click()` to attach the event handler to this link. My browser is Firefox 8 on Windows 7. Also verified the issue in Firefox 11.0a1 with a different profile and Chrome 16 so it isn't a configuration problem.

I tried reproducing with this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("a").click(function()
    {
      alert("click");
    });
  });
</script>
<a href="#">test</a>
```

But my link can be triggered both with mouse clicks and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Edit**: I realize that pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will have the desired effect. But sometimes tabbing to the actual control comes more natural.

Comment: Using the Esc key has always been the natural way to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  No need to thank us for this super-speedy fix!